# What is the best way to move my installed ubuntu form one disk to another

Tags: boot, partitioning, system-installation, mount

I would like to move the entire Linux/Ubuntu installation from a 1TB HDD to a 256GB SSD. There is hardly anything on the 1TB drive so I am confident everything will fit on the SSD drive.
I want to make that my boot drive and use the 1TB drives for data storage, e.g. my personal home drive. Eventually, I'd like to add RAID to my several 1TB drives, but that's a different story.

Any advice for to get started with moving the operating system? I'm still on quite a learning curve.

Here is results of fdisk -l

```
joe@joeslinux:~$ sudo fdisk -l
[sudo] password for joe: 
Disk /dev/loop0: 1.6 MiB, 1654784 bytes, 3232 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop1: 81.7 MiB, 85639168 bytes, 167264 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop2: 81.6 MiB, 85549056 bytes, 167088 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop4: 1.6 MiB, 1658880 bytes, 3240 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop5: 94.9 MiB, 99446784 bytes, 194232 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop6: 81.7 MiB, 85692416 bytes, 167368 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 238.5 GiB, 256060514304 bytes, 500118192 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: C866B86E-2F90-4F99-9D6A-B56901D6D4AC


Disk /dev/sda: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xee260f95

Device     Boot   Start        End    Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *       2048     999423     997376  487M 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       1001470 1953523711 1952522242  931G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       1001472 1953523711 1952522240  931G 8e Linux LVM

Partition 2 does not start on physical sector boundary.


Disk /dev/sdb: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x76221e63


Disk /dev/sdc: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x000680a0

Device     Boot Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdc1        2048 1953525167 1953523120 931.5G 83 Linux


Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root: 867.2 GiB, 931097739264 bytes, 1818550272 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1: 63.9 GiB, 68589453312 bytes, 133963776 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Use the Backups program to backup the OS you want to move.
2. Install Ubuntu on the new hard drive.
3. Restore the backup on the Ubuntu OS running on the new drive.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Steps 1 and 2 went swimmingly well. For the restore on step 3,  I got this error -- No space left in ‘/media/joe/7685efc1-8e78-4f7c-9365-03ac32d8e534’.

Comment: About the space ... I checked and indeed there was no space left after the aborted restore attempt. But that's not right. The newly installed Ubuntu 14.4 LTS used 4.2GB out of a 187GB volume. The original installation took 74GB. The backup volume with all the diftar.gz files for some reason eats up 112.7GB for some reason. But even that's enough for the 170GB free space on the new SSD. I don't understand what happened. Is there more to step 3 than just restore? For example I am asked where to restore? What is the correct answer? When I ran it, I answered with '/'.